# Permission denied for SSH aws ec2 centos instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, centos7

So until now I have setup everything for deploying rails project to my ec2 centos instance.
while doing some stuff I did the following changes in

### etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes

#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

and unfortunately at same time logged out from the server.
and this is the moment when I realized how stupid I am.
while attempting to ssh into server, it says

### Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

anyone please advise any other possible way to solve this problem.
also I hear about following stuff.

- stopping the ec2 instance
- detach its volume
- attach it to new instance (created in the same zone)
- do correct the stupidity
- attach the volume again to original instance

But Unluckily I have **limited permissions to my account at aws consloe** right now.

Comment: What permissions do you have to the AWS account overall? The list above are all tasks you can accomplish via the AWS CLI, if you have credentials and permissions.

Comment: yes I do have an account to aws but with limited permissions.would you please mention which permission I need exactly.so I can ask my senior.

Comment: Looks like you're only working with EC2, so the arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess policy should work for you.

Comment: once I have this permission. what would you suggest to resolve this issue.